# VirtualBox上にインストールしたUbuntuにアクセスする方法

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox

量子計算シミュレーションを実行するためにUbuntuが必要になりました。
ファイルをUbuntuのterminalから開いて実行するのですが、
mac osxからUbuntuへとファイルを移行させる必要があります。
その具体的な手段について質問です。
現在はVirtualBoxを使用しています。
毎回起動して、またdesktopのスケールもあっていないので(225％にはしました)とてもやりづらいです。
dockerやParallels Desktopが検索結果としては多かったのですが、皆様のご意見を伺いたく思います。

Comment: 質問としては「ホスト(Mac)とゲスト(Ubuntu)でファイルのやり取りをする方法を知りたい」ということでしょうか？ / 挙げられた候補のいずれを使っても、予めゲストOS(やコンテナ等)を起動しておく手間が必要になるのは理解していますか？

Comment: 理解しています。実際に現在はubuntuをvirtual boxで入れてsshでmacからアクセスしていますが、他にもっといい方法があるか、ないのかというのがメインになります。

Answer (score 0):

パッと思いついた手段を列挙します。

- mac 上で編集したファイルを ubuntu へ scp でコピーする
- mac 上で編集したファイルを ubuntu から tftp で get する(mac 上に tftp サーバーを設定する必要あり。ubuntu にも tftp クライアントが必要)
- mac から ubuntu を sshfs マウントして ubuntu 上のファイルを編集する(mac 上に sshfs をインストールする必要あり(おそらく))
- mac から ubuntu を NFS マウントして ubuntu 上のファイルを編集する(ubuntu 上に NFS サーバーを設定する必要あり)
- mac 上の VScode で remote 編集する(参考 [VSCodeのRemote Development機能が革命的な話。 - Crieit](https://crieit.net/posts/VSCode-Remote-Development) )

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBoxであれば**共有フォルダ**という機能を使ってホストOS・ゲストOS間でファイルのやり取りを行う事ができますが、予めゲストOS側で**Guest Additions**のインストールが必要となります。

画面解像度の問題も上述のGuest Additionsをインストールすることで、ゲストOS側での解像度を細かく設定できるようになるはずです。
(私自身はmacOSに詳しくないので、関連しそうな情報の紹介に留めます)

参考：
[How to access a shared folder in VirtualBox? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/161759/902344)